# A function which has limit just at integer values

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

The question is so simple.
Find a functon like $f$ such that it has limit , just at integer values.
My try ( Which i don't know if is true ) :

1. $f$ is defined just on integer values such that for $x \in \mathbb Z$, $f(x)=x$
2. Another funtion that i think may be true is for $x \in \mathbb Z$, $f(x)=0$. Also if $|y-x|=0.2$ , then $f(y)=0$ . But if $|y-x| \neq 0.2$ , then $f(y)=(-1)^{p}$ for $y \in Q : y=\frac{p}{q}$ and $f(y) = 2$ for $y \notin Q.$

Are any of these two answers correct? Provide a better one if you can.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I find this question unclear. What do you mean by having a limit? Do you mean that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ exists if and only if $a\in \mathbb{Z}$? Should the domain of $f$ be $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Mathematician42 yes, that's exactly what i mean

Answer (score 1):

I provide a "general" way to find such function.

Take the function $f(x)$ defined in $\mathbb{R}$ which is equal to $\sin(\pi x)$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and it is $0$ otherwise. You can replace $\sin(\pi x)$ with any  function $h$ which is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $h^{-1}(0)=\mathbb{Z}$. Another possible choice is $h(x)=\min(x-\lfloor x\rfloor,1-x+\lfloor x\rfloor)$.

Answer (score 0):

Define a periodic function with period one by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
2x & \mbox{ if } x\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,\frac{1}{2}],\\
-2x & \mbox{ if } x\in (\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})\cap [0,\frac{1}{2}],\\
2-2x & \mbox{ if } x\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [\frac{1}{2},1],\\
-2+2x & \mbox{ if } x\in (\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})\cap[\frac{1}{2},1].
\end{cases}$$

This one function is only continuous in $\mathbb{Z}$.

This is more or less the same as the other $2$ answers.